# Keep button disabled till the current page reloads (using Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a search bar in `index.php` and when I type an ID, the SQL data is fetched from `fetch.php`. The fetch.php contains "AddToZip" button for each row of SQL data. When I click on a selected button, the selected button is disabled (going properly till here). But when I clear the search bar to write a different ID or perhaps same ID, all the disabled buttons of "AddToZip" are reactivated/enabled. How do I keep them disabled when the user uses the search bar multiple times and they anyhow get enabled only when the user refreshes the page.

index.php

```
<php code>

<?php
session_start();
...
...
...
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>LiveData</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Live Data Search</h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by ID" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    
   </div>
   <p>
        <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
        
    </p>
    
   <br />
   <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
</html>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var txt = $(this).val();
        if(txt != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetch.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {search:txt},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        else
            if(txt == '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"null.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {search:txt},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        
            
    });
});

</script>

<script>

    var addToZip = function(id, btn) {
        $.ajax({
        
        url:"AddToZip.php?id=" + id,
        success: function(data) {
            btn.disabled = true;
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
...

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '<h4 align = "center">Search Result</h4>';
 $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table bordered">
                   <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>                                 
                    </tr>';
                    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
                
        $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToZip(\''.$row["ID"].'\', this)"><i class="fa fa-pdf" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Add to Zip</button></td>
                </tr>
            ';
    }
    echo $output;
    
}
...

?>
```

Comment: Please replace your php code by pure html output from browser.

Comment: @Reporter as requested I have added the index.php purely from page's view source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add the code of *AddToZip.php* ?

You could store all **ids** into a session value, and check if the id is containt inside this array on your *fetch.php*.

AddToZip.php :

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids']))
    $_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids'] = [];
if (array_search($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids']) === false)
    $_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids'][] = $_GET['id'];
```

fetch.php :

```
<?php
...

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids']))
    $_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids'] = [];

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '<h4 align = "center">Search Result</h4>';
 $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table bordered">
                   <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>                                 
                    </tr>';
                    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
                
        $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                    <td><button '.(array_search($row["ID"], $_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids']) === false ? '' : 'disabled').' type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToZip(\''.$row["ID"].'\', this)"><i class="fa fa-pdf" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Add to Zip</button></td>
                </tr>
            ';
    }
    echo $output;
    
}
...

?>
```

And to clear the stored values, you have two solutions :

1. Keep other session datas

   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids']))
   unset($_SESSION['added_to_zip_ids']);
2. Clear everything

   session_start();
   session_unset();

These line can be anywhere on the server.

Comment: Hey thanks alot it works. Just one question, how do I end this session to reactivate all disabled AddToZip buttons? That is can I end the session from another php page when its called such as "Download.php" or what could be a better solution?

Comment: I can award the bounty only by tomorrow. So will award you by tomorrow for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the event handler 'keyup' (as you already do) and / or the 'change' handler to activate a function (e.g. check_disable_status)

```
$('#search_text').keyup(check_disable_status)
$('#search_text').change(check_disable_status)
```

and you should start this function also on "ready" state of the DOM.

In this function you just check the current "STATE" of your field, or maybe other dependencies for your business logic and set the field always in ENABLED or DISABLED state.

Comment: Hi thank you. But I did not understand how to use check_disable_status. Could you please demonstrate with an example?

Comment: Hi, 

just create a JS function:

check_disable_status = function(){

let my_element = $(this) // this = the search_text element -> transform it to a jquery element

// now check your business logic
// for e.g. if my_element is empty -> set my_element as disabled, or what ever you have to check (i dont know what is relevant for disable or enable your field)

}

Comment: No sorry but this does not support my logic. The Fetch.php is actually reenabling the disabled buttons as it refreshes the whole session. I guess I need a function to call from there to keep the disabled buttons - disabled.

Comment: Hey Saif, i think the problem is in this part of your js code: